# JSON URL retreival and Parsing Basics. Pro Network Admin, Newbie Java Programmer

Tags: json, parsing, url, object

I am have been wanting to learn programming outside of unix for a long time. I finally have a project and the drive to start. What i want to acccomplish is use my bluetooth barcode scanner in my kitchen to scan UPC codes of finished food products. These UPC codes will then be scraped against UPC Database | Free information on thousands of products.. This site offers an API for retreiving data in either XML or JSON. Throught a little digging i found that I JSON is the easier to work with, but this is where i get lost, i did some reading on json parsers and such, but i think i am really in over my head. I beleive my main issue is finding out how to scrape the url for data and then how to get the data into objects.

My code so far:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class barcode {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{


//Barcode read and append to URL
String UPC;
UPC = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter UPC");
String URL;
URL = "http://www.upcdatabase.org/api/json/*personal API KEY*/";
String barcode;
barcode = URL + UPC;


//Filewrite Process

FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt",true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write(barcode + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
//Close the output stream
out.close();
```

Comment: Cool idea for a hack. Hope you get there!

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) it can parse the response of that site (if it is proper json) directly to objects.

Not to be nasty, but from the looks of your code you have some ways to go. Maybe you could get some help on this one so you learn to program faster?